# How does one Configure Serilog to WriteTo AzureBlobStorage via the Storage Account Uri or a Named Connection String from appSettings.json?

Tags: configuration, serilog, .net-6.0, appsettings, azure-secrets

Serilog configures properly when the following section. *which exposes connectionString*, is added to appSettings.json:

```
"Serilog": {
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "AzureBlobStorage",
      "Args": {
        "connectionString": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=...;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
        //"connectionStringName": "MyStorageConnectionName",
        //"storageAccountUri": "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net",
        "storageContainerName": "myapplogs",
        "storageFileName": "MyApp {yyyy}-{MM}-{dd}.log",
        "writeInBatches": "true", // mandatory
        "period": "0.00:00:30", // mandatory
        "batchPostingLimit": "50" // optional
      }
    }, ...
  ],
}
```

While the above works, I have thus far been unable to replace use of the **connectionString** property with either **connectionStringName** or preferably **storageAccountUri** (simply leveraging Managed Identities.)

I have added the **Serilog.Settings.Configuration 3.3.0** package as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54522745/4552096); and I am configuring Serilog as follows:

```
static void createLogger(ConfigureHostBuilder host) {
  host.UseSerilog((ctx, lc) => {
    lc.ReadFrom.Configuration(ctx.Configuration);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using a very similar configuration...
I was able to get it to work with ConnectionStringName but NOT with the storageAccountUri (which would be preferable to be able to use Managed Identity)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).